# html-страница не обрабатывает PHP код на LAMP сервере

Tags: php, html, ubuntu, lamp

**Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS**

**PHP7**

если создать файл `ex1.html` с содержанием:

```
Today is <?php echo date("l"); ?>.
```

,то браузер отображает:

> Today is .

при этом если создать файл `ex1.php` с содержанием:

```
<?php echo " Today is " . date("l") . ". " ; ?>
```

,то браузер выводит:

> Today is Saturday.

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело не в *LAMP* сервере. По умолчанию `php` код воспроизводиться только в `.php` файлах. Чтобы отображать его в `.html` файлах необходимо сделать следующее...

В файл `.htaccess` добавьте:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Если данного файла нет, то создайте его сами.

> Действия директивы **.htaccess** распространяется на все вложенные папки.

---

С `.htaccess`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Без `.htaccess`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все еще нет вывода

Answer (score 0):

оказалось, что apache не обрабатывал .htaccess,
проблема решалась добавлением в файл /etc/apache2/apache.conf 
в блок

```
<Directory «путь до директории с вашим htaccess»>…</Directory>
```

строчки

```
AllowOverride All
```

для других версий, например FreeBSD, это файл /usr/local/etc/apache/httpd.conf

после чего в файл .htaccess следовало добавить:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

спасибо @Egor, за верно указанное направление для поиска.

Comment: Хотел вам предложить проверить настройки apache, так как только в нём и могла быть проблема. Хорошо, что вы сами смогли решить её.